# Из приложения скачать выбранное приложение с play market

Tags: android, apk, download, playmarket

Есть приложение, своего рода небольшой каталог популярных софтин, реально ли как то скачивать выбранное пользователем приложение сразу в папку загрузки и оттуда уже открывать и запускать установку? Ну или пусть он сам устанавливает и запускает но хотя бы скачивать не отправляя его в play market?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Официального api для этого нет. Как вариант, можно логиниться под Google аккаунтом и качать как будто вы качаете из браузера.

Что-то подобное делает [android-market-api](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/). Использовать [так](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-market-api/wikis/HowDownloadApps.wiki):

```
// создаём новую сессию
MarketSession session = new MarketSession(true);
session.login(login,password, androidId);

// качаем
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android-Market/2 (sapphire PLAT-RC33); gzip");
conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookieName + "=" + cookieValue);

// сохраняем локально
InputStream inputstream = (InputStream) conn.getInputStream(); 
String fileToSave = assetId + ".apk"; System.out.println("Downloading " + fileToSave); 
BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileToSave)); 
byte buf[] = new byte[1024]; 
int k = 0; 
for(long l = 0L; (k = inputstream.read(buf)) != -1; l += k )
     stream.write(buf, 0, k); 
inputstream.close(); 
stream.close();
```

Comment: тут как я понимаю надо использовать данные пользователя? а если я не хочу просить ввод данных у пользователя а просто скачать и предложить установку или установить не напрягая юзера лишними действиями, есть такой вариант? просто не хотелось бы лишнюю инфу просить у юзера что бы было более чисто и аккуратно.

Comment: @Mass не думаю, что так возможно. В GP всё завязано на регионы, без аккаунта никак не скачать.

Comment: я не хочу юзеру давать форму вода логин/пароль от его акка, это личная инфа, мне бы только кидать или как то загружать приложение с минимальным участием пользователя.
Суть приложения именно в упрощении действий, своего рода каталог приложений который нужен каждому, из серии drp.su для андройда, где вся установка проходит на автомате, юзер только выбрал галочками нужное. Как такое осуществить?

Comment: Может есть готовое решение где можно позаимствовать или на основе чего собрать